# Is overly used RAM a bottleneck

Tags: mysql, performance

We have a MySQL DB server with the below configuration.

**Capacity**:

- CPU - 4 cores
- RAM - 16 GB
- Memory - 150 GB

We are having performance issues with queries that work fine in the local development environment but take more time in the PROD environment. Upon investigation, I found around 800 connections opened from multiple services (about 12), and the RAM is 93% used. Do those 800 connections have bloated RAM, causing any performance issues?

**Utilisation:**

- CPU usage is around 20-30%
- Used RAM Memory - 93%
- Used SWAP - 95%

Comment: Active swap usage is definitely a red flag, often it is the cause of degraded performance on a database server. In some environments I have worked in, swap is disabled on the database server, because there's no point in having it. It's up to you to manage memory consumption of mysqld and any other processes, to avoid swap activity.

Comment: Use the slowlog to find the "worst" queries, then discuss them.  Meanwhile, RAM and SWAP are dangerously high.  Lower `innodb_buffer_pool_size` by, say, 10% of RAM just to play it safe.  What are the values of `max_connections` and `Max_used_connections`?

Comment: Please post your code that accomplishes "Connect", "Process" and "Close/Disconnect".  It is likely someone missed the Close/Disconnect, leaving resources in use for processes that are Sleeping, when they should have been ended hours ago.